# Why does React expose minified versions of commonjs modules in production?

Tags: reactjs

React has recently started exposing minified versions of commonjs modules in production mode ([source](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/npm/index.js#L4)).

Is there any advantage of this over just letting consumers minify the final application bundles as a part of their build process. This seems a better solution given that minifier can then do whole program level optimizations and dead code elimination.

While libraries frequently publish minified CDN builds, exposing minified modules (which depends on other modules) seems fairly unorthodox.